# Strategy for selling/buying a stock by average reward value iteration

Tags: markov-process, dynamic-programming

At beginning of any day $t$, I may own $0$ or $1$ share. The price of the share follows the Markov chain in the table below. At the beginning of a day where I own a share, I may either sell at today’s price or keep. At the beginning of a day where I don’t have a share, I may either buy or not buy. Find the value iteration  to maximize the expected discounted profit over an infinite horizon (use $b = 0.95$).

Today's price/Probability of Tomorrow's price

$0$/          $P(0)=0.5$,  $P(1) = 0.3$, $P(2)= 0.1$, $P(3)=0.1$

$1$/          $P(0)=0.1$,  $P(1)=0.5$,    $P(2)=0.2$, $P(3)=0.2$

$2$/          $P(0) = 0.2$, $P(1)= 0.1$,  $P(2)=0.5$, $P(3)=0.2$

$3$/         $P(0) = 0.1$, $P(1)= 0.1$,  $P(2)=0.3$, $P(3)=0.5$

**My attempt:** I'm trying to construct the value iteration equation with infinite horizon: $V_{k+1}(i) = \max_{k} (c_{ik} + \beta\sum_{j=1}^{4} P_{ij}(k)V_{j}(n))$. I define state $i$ as whether I have a share ($i=1$) or not ($i=0$) at the beginning of day $t$, and $c_{ik}$ denotes the cost when in state $i$ ($i=0, 1$). But I'm not sure if $c_{ik}$ means anything, because the stock price tomorrow is not affected by the action we take. Thus, I think there is no cost matrix in this problem. Is this correct?

Can someone please help me with this problem? Really appreciate your inputs.

Comment: No one could help me with this problem? I'm thinking of eliminating $c_{ik}$ completely from the equation, as for any given state $i$, the action $k$ is irrelevant to the stock price. The key point is to buy the stock whenever it's at $0$ or $1$, and to sell it at $2$ or $3$. Now, comparing the expected value between $t$ and $t+1$ for buying at $0$ and buying at $1$, we would obtain the optimal strategy. Is this the correct thought?

Comment: $c_{ik}$ is the profit from selling a share (or cost of buying a share) in period $k$ - it is most certainly relevant.

Comment: @Math1000: but the action we take does not "really" change $c_{ik}$ isn't it? Could you help solve this problem?